# How to remove all filename extensions from a string?

Tags: grep

I have filenames with MP4 extensions that do not end with `_special.MP4`:

```
mylist=$(ls | grep -v "_special.MP4")
```

Then, I'd like to remove the `.MP4` extension from this subsequent list.

```
echo $mylist | sed -e 's/\.MP4$//'
```

only remove the last `.MP4` occurrence, how can I get them all?

Comment: It's not a good idea to parse the output of `ls` and `sed` can't operate on filenames. It can only operate on the contents of files or standard output. You'll want to use a utility like `rename`.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Quoting `"$mylist"` may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say I have these files that end in .MP4:

```
.
├── 1.MP4
├── 2.MP4
└── 3_special.MP4
```

If I understand correctly, you want the names of the non-special files, minus the .MP4 extension.

First of all, I would use `find` instead of `ls` because it's easier to control and easier to parse the output. Either way, you'll end up with a list files separated by newline characters:

```
$ find . -name '*.MP4' -not -name '*_special.MP4'
./1.MP4
./2.MP4
```

Your sed command will work as is because the `$` in the pattern binds to the end of each line:

```
$ find . -name '*.MP4' -not -name '*_special.MP4' | sed -e 's/\.MP4$//'
./1
./2
```

---

The [`basename`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html#tag_20_07) command will actually do most of this for you; you don't even need `sed`! The primary use of `basename` is to remove the directory from the front of a path, but it also supports removing suffixes.

> SYNOPSIS
>
> basename string [suffix]

`basename` only accepts a single word in the "string" position, so you need to use xargs to run it once for each file.

```
$ find . -name '*.MP4' -not -name '*_special.MP4' | xargs -I -name- basename -name- .MP4
1
2
```

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
shopt -s extglob            # enable extglob
mylist=( !(*_special.MP4) ) # fill array but without files with suffix _special.MP4
echo "${mylist[@]%.MP4}"    # remove suffix .MP4
```